# Is there a way in CSS to prevent widows without having to use additional HTML?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, whitespace, word-wrap

I have a line of copy that is managed in a Content Management System. The CMS will not allow HTML or special characters like `&nbsp;` or `<span>`.

I've tried messing with margins and padding, but can't get anything to give me the intended result.

This is how the text is being rendered:

```
<h1>This is an example of the headline.</h1>
```

I want to prevent a widow (a lone word that appears at the bottom of a block of text) so when the line does break, it treats the last 2 words as 1 word.

For example, "the headline" would break to the next line instead of just "headline" all alone.

Is there a way to do this in CSS alone?

I would love to see "white-space: no-widow" in CSS, but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: no**, there's no way to do this that i know of.

*if* you could wrap those last two words in a span with a `no-wrap` style on it that might work. But I see you can't add a span in your CMS.

One thing you *could* do:
set the width of the `h1` in `em` units, so that its width is proportionate to the size of the text. This way you can set a width that forces the title to break where you want it to, and that width will scale with the text.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the game on this one, but if you're still looking for a solution this might help. New CSS property (sadly, [still unsupported by FF and Safari atm](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-wrap%3A%20balance)) called `text-wrap` (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-wrap).

So you could try:

```
h1 { text-wrap: balance; }
```

Hope this helps!